# CefSharp proxy-server

Tags: c#, proxy, cefsharp

I have an application which loads some pages and searches for some information and it should retrieve it. The problem is that no page load when I have a proxy set from LAN Settings. Without proxy, it works perfectly fine (as well as when I set the settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("no-proxy-server", "1"); ).
Could it be an HTTP timeout? I used this code (provided in CefSharp.Example) to detect the connection type:

```
switch (proxy.AccessType)
{
   case InternetOpenType.Direct:
    {
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("no-proxy-server","1");
        break;
    }
   case InternetOpenType.Proxy:
    {
       settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxyserver",proxy.ProxyAddress);
       break;
    }
   case InternetOpenType.PreConfig:
    {
       settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-auto-detect", "1");
       break;
    }
   default:
    {
       settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("no-proxy-server","1");
       break;
    }
}
```

I need to mention that the ProxyAdress is the exact same as the one I set in LAN settings.

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#proxy-resolution

Comment: If you require NTLM authentication then you'll have to search the CEF issue tracker for details